# Is it possible to put composite keys in models in Laravel 8?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I want to create a Model with a composite primary key, is there any way to do this in Laravel 8?

Comment: Chek this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64872762/how-to-use-composite-primary-key-in-laravel-8

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use composite primary key in laravel 8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64872762/how-to-use-composite-primary-key-in-laravel-8)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in your migration instead of using `id` use something like this:

```php
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->primary(['name', 'email']);
});
```

more information on https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations#available-index-types

When you want to access with Model, you can do something like this (since eloquent does not support composite `find`):

```php
$user = User->where(['name' => $name, 'email' => $email])->first();
```